# What does "they" and "that" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Kat describes about her husband:

> Kat: Sleeps 70 with crew. Two helicopters. Missile defenses.
>
> Protagonist: Afraid of pirates?
>
> Kat: Andrei lives playing one government off the other. The day **they**
> turn, **that**'s his refuge.

What does "they" and "that" refer to?

Source: Christopher Nolan's movie [*Tenet* (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenet_(film))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***They*** refers to *government* which is a [collective noun](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/collective-nouns.html) (refers to a group of people).

[image]

As for ***that***, it refers to the preceding clause ***the day when (or the fact that) the government will turn***. Meaning is a bit ambiguous, I can't be sure what *The day they turn* actually means, but probably it is clearer in the context of the book.

Comment: Turn means turn their back?

Comment: I am wondering... not clear. Because of the previous sentence _Andrei lives playing one government off the other._ it influences me to understand that maybe he means every time a government is followed by another. But I really don't know.